# Is it possible to get scenario inside the step in Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, scenarios

I need to make screenshot inside the step on specific place. It means not on @BeforeStep nor on @AfterStep. I need to call

```
// public void someStep(Scenario scenario)  // This does not work

public void someStep()
{
    page.openUrl();
    scenario.attach(screenshot(), "image/png", fileName1);
    page.doSomething();
    scenario.attach(screenshot(), "image/png", fileName2);
    page.doSomethingElse();
}
```

But I am not able to get current scenario related to the step execution. Is it possible or not? I tried to call it like someStep(Scenarion scenario) but it throws an error.

Comment: Can't you get the Scenario object via dependency injection to your step definition class? I know you can configure a DI framework for cucumber. I just don't have much experience in Java, that's all.

Comment: See https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/#dependency-injection

Comment: Thanks I thing I know what you mean. Don't know if I am able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the scenario object, your best bet is an AfterStep hook. However this is **not** supported in all flavours of cucumber. Your best bet is to check the docs or API documentation for your language

Comment: @AfterStep is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a simple DI (PicoContainer) example to access the Scenario from each step.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sharing-scenario-context-between-cucumber-step-using-dependency?trk=pulse-article_more-articles_related-content-card